# How to put value on Input box type Date using web browser in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

The problem is that when I put a value on input box `type=date` using `datetimepicker` and `textbox`, in the web browser the value will appear. But when you click on update information the web cannot accept the value.

I tried to get the tag name input and set attribute by `datetimepicker` and change format but the website will not accept it. I also tried set attribute by `textbox` and manually input the date and format I want but nothing happens.

You can visit the site: https://office.planpromatrix.com/login 
and use this dummy account for reference:

**username: gsmith1**

**password: 1234567890**

```vb
For Each element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
    If element.GetAttribute("type") = "date" Then
        element.SetAttribute("value", DateTimePicker1.Text)
        WebBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
    End If
Next
```

```vb
For Each element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
    If element.GetAttribute("type") = "date" Then
        element.SetAttribute("value", textbox1.Text)
        WebBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
    End If
Next
```

Comment: You code is missing context. Where/when are you trying to set these values? Also, note that the HTML page accepts date inputs based on the current culture. If you're setting this value in the Philippines, use the local Date format.